# help i neeed somone to tell me

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, hack

I received that amount from an unknown source. what also troubles me is that my wallet displaces a much larger amount than i received which i cant explain.my gool is to convert that amount to EUR but im afraid of a potential smart contract that involves a 99% fee which will be activated once i move the founds i read that this is a possibility on reddit plus the possibility of a hack. is there a way to securly transfer the worth of these founds to my bank account without losing it

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like a scam. Nobody gives away an important amount for nothing.